# Отправка данных из формы с PHP и Ajax

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

У себя н сайте нужно сделать отправку из формы. Долго мучался с PHP и Ajax, но разобраться не смог.

Пробовал такой код, но при нажатии на кнопку "Отправить" ничего на почту не приходит.

```
<?
if((isset($_POST['name'])&&$_POST['name']!="")&&(isset($_POST['phone'])&&$_POST['phone']!="")){
        $to = 'mail@yandex.ru';
        $subject = 'Обратный звонок';
        $message = '
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>'.$subject.'</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <p>Имя: '.$_POST['name'].'</p>
                        <p>Телефон: '.$_POST['phone'].'</p>                        
                    </body>
                </html>'; //Текст нащего сообщения можно использовать HTML теги
        $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
        $headers .= "From: Отправитель <from@example.com>\r\n";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

Comment: А где код отправки ajax? И проверьте вообще доходят ли письма из php, возможно у вас не установлен почтовый клиент.

Comment: Добавьте вывод echo 'test'; перед if и проверьте что вернет ajax. Возможно аякс не отправляет данные. Или как написали выше проблемы с mail()

Answer (score 1):

Возможно у Вас не установлен или не настроен SMTP, или почтовый сервис фильтрует сообщение как спам. Лучше использовать библиотеку типа PHPMailer

Answer (score 0):

Как говорилось выше возможно у вас не настроен SMTP. Возможно вы размещаете свой сайт на каком нить бесплатном хостинге например и в силу определенных обстоятельств вас сразу помечают как спам и тп. Совет попробуйте сначала отправить только текст, обычный, без всякого там html. Если в течении 30 минут не чего не пришло, читайте логи, там будет ясно отправляются ли письма вообще. Если сервер не ваш, а вы берете хостинг, пишите в тех поддержку он что нибудь да прояснят.

Answer (score 0):

Использовал этот же скрипт. Письма не отправлялись пока скрипт был в отдельном файле. Когда перенес его в index.php все заработало... Но это конечно же не решение.